# Sorting arrays in PHP - numeric sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a bunch of numbers. 
Let's use these as an example:
7, 18, 24, 53, 75, 15

When i use rsort() on my array, it orders it something like this:

- 75
- 7
- 53
- 24
- 18

However, this is not what I want. I want my sorting algorithm to sort my array in numeric order descending, so that it looks like this:

- 75
- 53
- 24
- 18
- 15

What sorting algorithm is the right one? I've tried a few but none have done the trick.

Comment: Is it a number or string array.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is a number array

Comment: Give us a var_dump of the starting array itself!

Comment: There's your answer. The sorting method uses their Ascii value, which is not the same as their numerical value. You would have to convert them first.

Comment: convert them to what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `SORT_NUMERIC` flag:

```
rsort($myArray, SORT_NUMERIC)
```

Without flags, `rsort` (as well as `sort`) sorts *items* without changing types, i.e. strings are compared lexicographically.

Comment: I will give it the green tick when I can in 7 minutes haha